# How to handle C# COM events in QT?

Tags: c#, c++, qt, com

I have a simple C# COM visible library that looks like this:

```
namespace MyEventClassLibrary {

[Guid("0ab09e18-bf85-48c8-a45d-a0cebed77a5c")]
public interface ICalculator
{
    int Add(int Num1, int Num2);
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("9e09b634-8c1a-4926-83b2-f6f988595c85")]
public interface ICalculatorEvents
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void Completed(int Result);
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ICalculatorEvents))]
[Guid("6cebc4db-2e8f-4e24-91a5-24ffdf97fc6a")]
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void CompletedDelegate(int result);

    public event CompletedDelegate Completed;

    public int Add(int Num1, int Num2)
    {
        int Result = Num1 + Num2;
        if (Completed != null)
            Completed(Result);

        return Result;
    }
}}
```

I have it registered and I import the .TLB into QT with:

```
TYPELIBS = ..\MyEventClassLibrary\MyEventClassLibrary\bin\Debug\MyEventClassLibrary.tlb
```

and my *mainwindow.cpp* file looks like:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "myeventclasslibrary.h" 

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MyEventClassLibrary::Calculator eventClass;
    connect(&eventClass, SIGNAL(Completed()), this, SLOT(test()));

    qDebug() << eventClass.Add(1,2);
}

void MainWindow::test()
{
    qDebug() << "Here";
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

<s>When I build the project in QT though, I get 40+ issues along the lines of:</s>

```
MyEventClassLibrary.h:144: error: C2535: 'MyEventClassLibrary::CompletedDelegate::CompletedDelegate(void)': member function already defined or declared
```

and

```
MyEventClassLibrary.h:147: error: C2065: 'iface': undeclared identifier
```

*The above has been resolved by adding [ComVisible(false)] to the delegate (see comments for more info)*

When I run the code I get an error of:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal MyEventClassLibrary::Calculator::Completed()
```

My question is, **how do you handle events/delegates in COM and QT?**

As background info, the QT Documentation says:

> If the COM object implements the IDispatch interface, the properties, methods and events of that object become available as Qt properties, slots and signals.

and I've used the following as resources and research:

[Handle C# COM events in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923717/handle-c-sharp-com-events-in-c)

[how to put IDispatch* in managed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472700/how-to-put-idispatch-in-managed-code)

[How to fire c# COM events in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488379/how-to-fire-c-sharp-com-events-in-c)

and more; Please help!

Comment: Without knowing anything about the generated .h file, it sounds like too much of your implementation is visible.  The CompletedDelegate type should not be visible at all.  Project > Properties > Application tab > Assembly Information button and untick the "Make assembly COM-visible" option.  Apply the [ComVisible(true)] attribute only on the declarations that should be visible, the interfaces and the class.  Or apply [ComVisible(false)] on the delegate.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, that did fix the onslaught of errors I faced. While it will compile now and I can call the method _Add(int, int)_, I'm still unable and unsure how to instantiate & access the event _Completed_. I've tried `connect(&eventClass, SIGNAL(Completed()), this, SLOT(test()));`,but that doesn't seem to be correct.
Specifically, the error I get is: **QObject::connect: No such signal MyEventClassLibrary::Calculator::Completed()**

Comment: You know the solution to this question.  So complete the Q+A by posting the answer and accepting it.  Then click the Ask Question button to ask for help with your next problem.

Comment: If that's necessary I can do that, but the question I asked was "how do you handle events/delegates in COM and QT?". Fixing the multitude of errors was one concern, but that's not my main question.  I can update the question body with this new information, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question had a 2-part question, with the goal of getting a C# COM-visible event to fire in QT:

1. When I initially built the QT application, I was getting 40+ errors due to a delegate being visible. **This was resolved by adding [ComVisible(false)] above the delegate declaration** Thank you @HansPassant.
2. When this was resolved, I tried to connect a SLOT to the COM SIGNAL, with QT saying it couldn't find the *Completed* event. **This was resolved by matching up the function prototypes; Completed has a parameter of *int*, I was not including the *int* in the SLOT function**. (derp)

My original connect was:

```
connect(&eventClass, SIGNAL(Completed()), this, SLOT(test()));
```

it should have been:

```
connect(&eventClass, SIGNAL(Completed(int)), this, SLOT(test(int)));
```

Thanks!